# What does Tony Stark mean by "I will waive my customary retainer" at the end of Iron Man 2?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, dialogue, iron-man, iron-man-2

What does Tony Stark mean by "Then again I will waive my customary retainer... in exchange for a small favor." at the end of Iron Man 2?

What does this line mean?

Comment: Fury doesn't say that. https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_at_Stark_Expo#Aftermath And WRT consulting and retainers: https://www.consultingsuccess.com/2-types-of-consulting-retainers-and-how-to-use-them-effectively

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [**How to Ask**](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tony says that, not Nick.

Fury had just told Tony that they wanted to use him as a consultant, rather than as a full member of The Avengers. Normally, when you use a consultant, you have to pay them by the hour for the work that they do. Tony says that Fury wouldn't be able to afford him, but that he would not charge him if he does him a favor. That favor being to get Senator Stern to introduce them in Washington.

[Full conversation](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/Iron_Man_2):

> Fury: Which leads us to believe at this juncture we’d only like to use you as a consultant. [Tony stands and offers his hand. They shake]
>
> Tony: [Clasping his other hand on top of Fury’s] You can’t afford me. [Goes to leave, but turns around again] Then again, I will waive my customary retainer in exchange for a small favour. Rhodey and I are being honoured in Washington and we need a presenter.
>
> Fury: I’ll see what I can do.

Comment: What is the favour he asks for?

Comment: @ShanikaEdiriweera Re-read the answer, it says pretty clearly what the favour is.